# Amount of time boiling gnocchi

Tags: gnocchi

When boiling potato gnocchi, I'm told that they should remain in the water until they float to the top.

My question is, what happens to them the longer they remain in the boiling water?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they stay too long, they soak up water, get soggy or mushy and finally disintegrate, leaving you with a rather weird kind of lumpy potato soup.